# 動画のループ再生を、切れ目なく滑らかにしたい

Tags: delphi, 動画

動画のループ再生で、ループの瞬間に間が空いて黒くチラついて困ってます。
Twitterなどで見られるような、滑らかなループ再生を実装したいです。

■私が試したこと
　Delphi10.4 にて、ActiveX から Windows Media Player を利用し
　mp4（H.264-AAC）を、そのままループ再生しました。

```
type
    wmp1: TWindowsMediaPlayer;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if OpenDialog1.Execute then begin
    wmp1.URL := OpenDialog1.FileName;
    wmp1.controls.play;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  wmp1.Align := alClient;
  wmp1.settings.setMode('loop',true);
end;
```

１ループ目は、滑らかに再生されるのですが
　２ループ以降、一瞬真っ暗になってチラつくように再生されます。
　ビルドしてみても変わりませんでした。

■他の動画再生ソフトでは
　同じ動画ファイルを「MPC-BE」というフリーソフトで再生すると、ずっと滑らかにループ再生されます。
　このことから動画ファイル自体には問題はないようです。
　プリインストールソフトウェアの方のWindowsMediaPlayerでループ再生してみると３周に１回くらいの割合でチラつきます。
　なぜチラついたり、滑らかだったり、安定しないのかも疑問です

Answer (score 0, accepted):

質問者です。
その後、自分のパソコンの動画コーデックをすべて削除し、新しいコーデックパックに入れ直しました。
相変わらずWindowsMediaPlayerではチラつきますが
Delphiコンポーネントである TMediaPlayer で試したところMP4が再生できるようになり
そちらではチラつくことなく滑らかにループ再生することが出来ました。

結局、WindowsMediaPlayerがチラつく原因は不明ですが
そちらは私のプログラムの問題というより、ソフトウェア固有の問題のようですので
この質問を解決済みとしたいと思います。